# Android Tabhost inside a Tabhost

Tags: android

I created a tabhost in main_activity,
inside the tabhost, i created another tabhost.
i used same code on both tabhost:

android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm =   getSupportFragmentManager();
 android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

but when i replace fragment which the second tabhost created.
there is an error coming out

> E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f08004e (com.hrmini:id/realtabcontent_home) for fragment
>   HomeTabDaily{42e8e668 #1 id=0x7f08004e Daily}
>               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:939)
>               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
>               at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
>               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
>               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:454)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

How to get this error:

1. Open App.

   - The Tabhost Show up.(3 tabs -> tab1,tab2,tab3)
         - under the tabhost. tab1 will display another tabhost. Go to another Tab from Tabhost (tab2).
   - Under another tab (tab2)

     - Select a button which have a function to return to the tab that display another tabhost (tab1). and replace the fragment on
       tab1 to another fragment Error came out here.

Comment: Please provide the full stacks trace..

Comment: had post the full stacks trace